# convert .pem file to .p12 for push notification in ios

Tags: java, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

i am dealing with ios push notification.

the ios team send me two .pem certificates as apns certificate for send push. (named `apns-dev.pem` and `apns-dist.pem`).But the java package(`com.notnoop.apns`) support only p.12 file for send.Anybody please help which file should i convert to p.12 or convert both to a single p.12  ? ? or there is any other mathod is available in java for done push notification with .pem file

Comment: Ask your team to send you .p12 files only. There is no need to convert .pem tp .p12. They already have .p12 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apns-dev.pem` file is to be used while development and the `apns-dist.pem` is to be used for app store push notification.

You can refer this https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html
to convert your files.

Comment: There is everything in the answer.. Do you understand the difference between development and production..? If you wan't to send push while development and testing phase use dev. If your app is live in app store and people are using it then use dist.